# Upgrading pip You are using pip version 7.1.2 to version 8.1.2

Tags: python, terminal, installation, pip

Hi I am trying to upgrade my pip version to 8.1.2 
this command does not work:
    pip install --upgrade pip

And I also tried to get it directly from the github directory, like explained here https://github.com/pypa/pip/archive/8.1.1.zip but then i get the following error:

```
Checking .pth file support in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-21442.pth'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

I m working on a Mac btw

Comment: The answer is in the content you've posted, what happened when you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow it up with:

```
pip install -U pip
sudo !!
```

This has the same effect as:

```
sudo pip install -U pip
```

Or even better, move away from OS X's Python install, and instead install Python / pip via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install python
brew install python3
```

Comment: I tried brew install python and I get the following: `Error: You must `brew link gdbm` before python can be installed`

Comment: @malina Try running `brew doctor` and see if anything seems off.  Also make sure you're on the latest version of Homebrew (`brew update`) as permissions have changed recently.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open command prompt as an administrator, then try upgrade it, should works.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your user doesn't have write privileges to the `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` directory. That is what it means by `[Errno 13] Permission denied`

Try running the command with `sudo` prefixing the original command. Sudo allows you to safely run programs as root. You will need to type your password at the prompt.

Comment: Do you mean: `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`